# Can you use Metamagic Song and Quicken Spell together?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, bard, metamagic, spellcasting

The description for the feat **Metamagic Song** in *Races of Stone* states (emphasis mine):

> When you spontaneously cast an arcane spell that is enhanced by a metamagic feat, you can spend a number of uses of your bardic music ability equal to the number of extra levels that the metamagic feat imposes on the spell rather than raising the spell's effective level. *Applying metamagic spontaneously using this method increases the casting time of the spell normally.* You cannot use the Metamagic Song feat to add metamagic feats that would make the spell's effective level higher than the highest level of spell that you can cast normally.

Does the highlighted text mean that you can’t Metamagic song away the cost of a quickened spell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're casting spontaneously, you can't use [Quicken Spell](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#quickenSpell) at all.

> This feat can’t be applied to any spell cast spontaneously (including sorcerer spells, bard spells, and cleric or druid spells cast spontaneously), since applying a metamagic feat to a spontaneously cast spell automatically increases the casting time to a full-round action.

Comment: So it sounds like the highlighted text in Metamagic Song, is just confirming that the above rule still applies, correct?

Comment: @ConnorClarke That would be my assumption. There is an interesting argument to be made about how it interacts with things like the Rapid Metamagic feat, but that's worth a whole question of its own.

Comment: @Miniman it works with rapid metamagic as shown with metamagic specialist (alternative class feature for the sorcerer)

Answer (score 1):

## Yes you can, if you have the Rapid Metamagic feat

The *Rapid Metamagic* feat says:

> Benefit:
>   When you apply a metamagic feat to a spontaneously cast spell, the spell takes only its normal casting time
>
> Normal:
>   Spontaneous casters applying metamagic must either take a full-round action (if the spell normally requires a standard action or less) or add a full-round action to the casting time (if the spell takes 1 full round or longer to cast).

This is 100% confirmed to work as demonstrated with Metamagic Specialist (Alternative Class feature for the sorcerer) because the benefit is exactly the same.

The *Metamagic Specialist* feature says:

> Benefit: You can apply metamagic feats that you know to sorcerer spells without increasing the casting time. **This benefit even lets you quicken your sorcerer spells with the Quicken Spell feat.**

Otherwise it's not possible.

This question's answers confirm it: [Can Quicken Spell be used spontaneously if Rapid Metamagic is used?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/can-quicken-spell-be-used-spontaneously-if-rapid-metamagic-is-used)