# Can Quicken Spell be used spontaneously if Rapid Metamagic is used?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, metamagic, spellcasting

The **Quicken Spell** feat carries this special requirement:

> This feat can't be applied to any spell cast spontaneously (including sorcerer spells, bard spells, and cleric or druid spells cast spontaneously), since applying a metamagic feat to *a spontaneously cast spell automatically increases the casting time* to a full-round action.

This is in reference to this rule in the Metamagic SRD:

> Therefore, such a character must also take more time to cast a metamagic spell (one enhanced by a metamagic feat) than he does to cast a regular spell. If the spell’s normal casting time is 1 standard action, casting a metamagic version is a full-round action for a sorcerer or bard.

However **Rapid Metamagic** specifically supersedes this rule:

> When you apply a metamagic feat to a spontaneously cast spell, the spell takes only its normal casting time.

---

So...

Can **Quicken Spell** be used spontaneously *if* the casting time is reduced by **Rapid Metamagic**?

The way I read it, **Quicken Spell**'s special is more of an answer to a logistical question, rather than an explicit prohibition, given that it sites another effect(the spontaneous spell's increased casting time)as the reason for disallowing it. I see it similar to if the PHB said, "You can't wield three weapons since all playable races have only have two hands." If you somehow gained a third hand, the rule would cease to apply.

Comment: "sites" should be "cites" in the final paragraph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. The 'since' in the first quote implies **causality**: you can't quicken spontaneously cast spells **precisely and explicitly because** the casting time increases.

From the moment you got Rapid Metamagic, the casting time increases no more and Quicken Spell can apply.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes it works

There's also the alternative class feature for the sorcerer: *Metamagic specialist* (PHBII p.60) that confirms this works by RAW:

> Benefit: You can apply metamagic feats that you know to sorcerer
> spells without increasing the casting time. **This benefit even lets you
> quicken your sorcerer spells with the Quicken Spell feat**.

Since the benefit is exactly the same, it works with rapid metamagic too.